Fast leap year check
The task is to find parameters that make a fast leap year check correct for the widest range of years.
We assume the Proleptic Gregorian calendar, which extends the Gregorian calendar backward from its introduction in 1582 and includes a year 0. The standard way of checking for leap years is this:
bool is_leap_year(uint64_t year) {
    if (year % 4 != 0) return false;
    if (year % 100 != 0) return true;
    if (year % 400 == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

This gives the correct result for every year, but needs either several multiplications or data-dependent jumps, and could be a bottleneck. An alternative is a function of this form, for some constants f, m, and t:
bool fast_is_leap_year(uint64_t year) {
    return ((year * f) & m) <= t;
}

This compiles to efficient straight-line code which will take only about 7 cycles on a modern CPU. However, it is correct only for a limited number of years, depending on the chosen constants f, m, and t. This might be acceptable for certain applications.
The task is to find constants f, m, and t. The score to be maximized is the smallest year for which fast_is_leap_year with these constants returns the wrong result.
The constants can have at most 64 bit. All calculations are unsigned.

You are going to have to come up with a harder challenge!

@Simd Well, higher scores are still possible (although ovs's solution is probably good enough for all practical purposes).

Are you thinking of event planning in the year 1677721700?

Is this f,m,t method well known? Is there something I can search for about it? I understand how the overflow can get you 4's, but is there any intuition for how the 100/400 happen? (e.g. if I wanted to find some constants that are valid for 1900-2500, how would I, other than bruteforce?)

I haven't seen this method anywhere else, I found it mostly by chance. I don't have a good explanation on how it works (except for the year%4 part, as pointed out by ovs), would be happy to see one.

Some smaller provably optimal results: 8-bit f=1, m=3, t=0 with year=100; 12-bit f=1539, m=1839, t=296 with year=148; 16-bit f=24595, m=26187, t=1600 with year=300; 20-bit f=393379, m=409423, t=15872 with year=700; 24-bit f=6292111, m=6354959, t=63491 with year=3204. Solutions aren't unique.

@ExaltedToast What is the smallest to be correct up to 2100?

24 bits -- year=1700 is the best you can do with 23. (method: SAT/SMT solver)

@ExaltedToast I would love to see how you formulated the problem for a SAT/SMT solver

May be worth moving this to a chat, still working on this but it looks like beating @ovs's record with pure SAT isn't going to be tractable. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155249/fast-leap-year-discussion

Turns out due to an off-by-one, the above numbers all overcount the bits by 1, oops

Interesting concept! Note that the Gregorian leap year rule is only accurate for ~3300 years. We don't know what rule will be used in the far future. The mean tropical year length is fairly stable, but the mean solar day length is gradually getting longer because the Earth's rotation is slowing in a way that's not fully predictable.

I mean, if we're talking about when this method fails, the Sun is predicted to only have about 4.5 billion years left, so the solution may outlive the Earth itself.

year = 1677721700
f=2305843010244486103, m=6917529029721456652, t=2080374784

Verification program
binary representation of the parameters:
010000000000000000000000000000000111101011100001010001111010111
110000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000001100
000000000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000000000

The high bits in f and m take care of years not divisible by four, the low bits are found by bruteforce search. From looking at smaller results it seemed like m would always be \$2^k\times31+12\$ with \$t=2^k\times 31\$, so the search that found the current result made that assumption.

You solved it too quickly!

The low bits of f are floor(2^30 * (1 - 1/25)).  I would assume this fact is relevant.

year = 5965232500
(f, m, t) = (13835058055969358479, 13835058121854156815, 66571993088)

Try it in @ovs's verification program
In Binary:
1100000000000000000000000000000000101000111101011100001010001111
1100000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000000001111
0000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000000000000

How
Found and proven optimal with Z3 Theorem prover. I bounced around a bunch figuring out how to encode the problem as an SMT. It turns out that an iterative solution works really well here. We maintain a list of values to check, starting with just [0], and incrementally add to the checks:
seen_checks = set()
def find_constants(solver: z3.Solver, checks: list[int], bit_len: int) -> tuple[int, int, int]:
    global seen_checks
    f, m, t = z3.BitVecs("f m t", bit_len)

    for year in checks:
        if year in seen_checks:
            continue
        if is_leap(year):
            solver.add(z3.ULE((year * f) & m, t)) # ULE: unsigned less-eq
        else:
            solver.add(z3.UGT((year * f) & m,  t))
        seen_checks.add(year)

    result = solver.check()
    if result == z3.sat:
        model = solver.model()
        return tuple(map(lambda x: int(str(x)) if str(x) != 'None' else 0, (model[f], model[m], model[t])))
    else:
        print(f"Terminal result:", result)
        return None

This is wrapped with some plumbing that adds the earliest counterexample to the list of checks and asks for a new solution:
import z3

# ...

def validate(f, m, t) -> int:
    year = 0
    while True:
        fast_check = (year * f) & m <= t
        if fast_check != is_leap(year):
            return year
        year += 1

bit_len = 64
checks = [0]
solver = z3.Solver()
while (constants := find_constants(solver, checks, bit_len)) is not None:
    print("Found constants:", constants)
    counterex = validate(*constants)
    print("Earliest counterexample:", counterex)
    checks.append(counterex)

It happens that this doesn't lead to an explosion, the search space for constants starts filtering very rapidly: 32 bits is proven with only 131 such constraints, and this answer gets found after only 290 constraints. Originally I tried seeding the solver with lots values (say, the first 1000 ints), but this only slows it down as most values turn out to be irrelevant for solving. For example, most 2-digit integers don't show up in the final proof.
Eventually the solver outputs unsat, which means there provably exists no constants that will output correct results for every checked value. At that point, we know we've found optimal (but not necessarily unique) constants, and we output the constants that yielded the highest counterexample.
In this case, we get unsat after finding 294 such values, here they are sorted.
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,16,19,20,24,28,32,39,40,41,43,44,47,48,51,52,55,56,60,63,64,68,72,76,80,81,84,88,92,96,97,100,103,104,108,112,116,124,128,131,132,136,140,148,152,156,164,168,180,184,192,196,200,204,208,228,248,256,264,272,284,292,296,300,304,308,312,332,344,368,392,400,408,412,416,420,452,468,484,492,496,500,536,544,556,596,600,612,628,644,708,744,788,800,801,803,804,876,900,916,1000,1068,1076,1100,1124,1132,1300,1508,1528,1572,1588,1600,1628,1676,1776,1886,1888,1900,2000,2100,2108,2128,2148,2156,2200,2308,2400,2500,2600,2845,2847,2900,2988,3600,4196,4300,4308,4428,5200,5352,6800,7700,8000,8292,8352,8400,8504,8800,8852,9200,10000,10400,10800,11792,12000,12800,12900,12957,12959,13900,17068,18700,19284,25576,25600,25604,25700,25800,32868,33268,37492,38296,39064,42011,42012,42932,43692,46580,49000,51004,51200,51300,51400,58500,58515,58516,65536,65636,88769,89720,102400,102404,102500,116900,131172,174796,204800,204804,208880,233800,257004,262244,396900,406428,409600,409601,409700,524388,819200,819201,819204,819300,841524,844844,1638400,1638404,1638500,1651400,1673188,1681388,1683048,2097252,2184800,2524472,3276804,3276900,3346376,3365996,3383892,3744916,4365700,5018600,5228600,6423784,6553604,6731992,10457300,10508500,10924836,13107300,13256104,20649012,24403396,24672500,26214401,26214403,26214404,26214500,32095548,36472300,40046396,46684488,52428801,52428803,52428804,54024788,63161372,76260100,87039700,89478552,104857604,160739800,199765944,209715201,209715203,239674516,250289500,394758100,419430404,477218644,745654100,838860804,954437188,1073741924,1579032100,1677721604,2982616200,3355443204,4473924267,4473924268,5965232500


How many leap seconds will take place in that span of time?
